# How to pass session variable in postman

Tags: django-rest-framework, postman

I am having one issue with postman

I am having a code

```
if 'sample' in request.session:
    global_filters = request.session['sample']
```

This is the code in my django views .

But I don't know how can I pass this sample in postman for testing

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/django-session ,as per this session object is set on the  server side. Are you sure your framework expects client to set it ?

Comment: IF its need to be set by client , do you know how to set it from any other client application so that we can understand how it could be translated to postman implementation

Comment: Thanks bro , Actualy your first comment help me to understand the django session .

So I can pass it any method and I can update the request.session

Comment: I added that as answer could you please accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def setsession(request):  
    request.session['sname'] = 'irfan'  
    request.session['semail'] = 'irfan.sssit@gmail.com'  
    return HttpResponse("session is set")
```

https://www.javatpoint.com/django-session

So just see the above link as per the link the session object is set at server side . See if it helps